# My Unity Scene Was Lost but I still have the Scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was following a tutorial on how to make snake. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0QbmNZlxhw&list=PL1bPKmY0c-wnka3TTQhX7mfn9UoVXNP3H&index=1 When Unity crashed and I had not saved it once, however I still have the scripts for it. I tried to make it again but the map won't show up. I looked at the alpha but it was just fine. I need help finding out how to make the game again with the scripts.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Now, I'm no Unity expert but your question lacks details to be able to tell what's wrong. What does "the map won't show up" really mean? We need context. Is it some of your scripts that aren't working or is it some Unity assets that are missing?

Comment: So in the tutorial, he makes a checkered background, however, I don't see the background and I'm not sure what to do to make it show up.I'm not sure if it's the script or the assets. I'm very new to unity by the way.

Comment: It sounds like you weren't that far into building the game (considering you never saved it), so why don't you try starting over? That's probably gonna save you more time and perhaps you'll realize what was missing

Comment: Well, unfortunately you have to learn the hard way ;) start version controlling your code projects (e.g. using [git](https://git-scm.com/))! Regularly save and backup your progress! If the scene is nowhere saved so far there is no way to get it back, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck, save your scene frequently and before testing/building. If Unity crashes your scene/inspector changes will not recover. Your scripts, however, as they are separate files retain their changes.

Answer (score 0):

For avoiding this in the future I recommend you to use a [Version Control System](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-version-control)

And within the options of VCS I recommend to you [Git](https://git-scm.com/doc)